# Fill PDF using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jspdf, pdf-form

I plowed through all the other questions on fill the PDF via JavaScript. I'm kind of surprised there is really no lib that work out of the box or without doing some magic tricks around them.

I tried https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js which is unusable if you want to implement it by yourself (took me over an hour just to drop it out of hate). Demo works nice though so shame.

Also trying to use https://github.com/pdffillerjs/pdffiller but this one has some issues with reading file (ENOENT) - and yes, I triple checked if file is there and if address is correct (even put it in the same folder to make sure).

There's [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), but it's only for reading PDF's or creating PDF's from scratch, not for filling them out. I'm temporarly out of options - anyone can recommend what to use?

And sorry for using `javascript` tag but you can imagine that the other two tags are not gonna make it through. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

pdf-lib https://pdf-lib.js.org/ is one good option. It works well on form filling.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34017431)